# Primefaces dialog event for unmaximize?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsf, primefaces

My basic question is "Is there an event for unmaximize of dialog", i know i can register ajax for 'maximize' event but what about event that happeneds after comming back from full-screen mode back to normal size ?"

Description of the problem im facing right now:
"When dialog comes back from full-screen to normal mode, the scrolls disappear."

Contents of file:

```
<p:dialog ... width="600" height="400" maximize="true">
   <p:panel style="overflow:auto;">
      <p:dataTable style="min-width:800px !important;">
           ....cols/data ~height~600px;
      </p:dataTable>
   </p:panel>
</p:dialog>
```

On .show() action everything looks ok, same on resize action scrolls are rendered in correct way. Everything breaks up after UNmaximize action (comming back to normal size mode).

Primefaces ive tried and reproduced the problem are both my project version 3.5.RC1 and newest 5.2.

Assuming that in the newest version problem is still present, i need to implement some workaround, but wasnt able to :(

Comment: Found an Issue rised on Primefaces tracker for given problem: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4879&can=1&q=label%3DTargetVersion-3.5.23%20status%3AFixed&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How it was fixed :

Primefaces versions 3.5.23 and 4.0.7 and 5.0.0 have implemented work-around not resolving to unmaximize event as it is impossible to call that event only on unmaximize.

Work-around involves manual changes to saveState and restoreState of Dialog javascript in file primefaces.js. Methods are ment to save and restore the width and height of the content of a dialog.

Best way is to port solution from higher version of primefaces or elite version to 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

The PrimeFaces documentation of the dialog states, that there is an **minimize**, **maximize** and **move** event.

Try using

```
<p:ajax event="minimize" listener="#{bean.listener}" update="controls" />
```

inside your p:dialog.

Comment: Hello, minimize event is fired after minimize button is pressed. Maximize when maximize button. But im searching for event fired on "going back to normal mode". Maximize/minimize only fire on expanding/declining of view, but when you press button again to come back to "input" dialog size -> nothing happends. Im currently working on workaround this problem with custom JavaScript but i thought Primefaces would provide a better event management than i would personally...

Answer (score 0):

i don't know and did not checked for primefaces < 6 but since then there is no workaround required. You can make use of the ajax events like the following:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="myDialog"
    header="Dialog"
    onShow="updateClientSide()"
    modal="true" blockScroll="true" responsive="true"
    closable="true" closeOnEscape="true" maximizable="true"
    height="80vh" width="80vw" minHeight="300" minWidth="330">
    
    <p:ajax event="maximize" update="{id's to update}" onstart="updateClientSide()" process="@none"/>
    <p:ajax event="restoreMaximize" update="id's to update" onstart="updateClientSide()" process="@none"/>
    
    <div>
        content
    </div>
</p:dialog>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateClientSide() {
        your client side stuff
    };
</script>
```

Please note that the given example is for client side callbacks only, if you want to handle things on the server side you need to add a listener to the p:ajax tag and update the process value for the partial request to your needs.

regards

EDIT: Please mention the comment from Kukeltje to perform pure client side callbacks with the help of primefaces extensions framework. By utilizing the pe:javascript libtag one can still use the events provided by the given primefaces component but the cycle to the server side gets skipped completely.

Comment: If you really want pure client-side callbacks, try using `pe:javascript` from PrimeFaces extensions.